# Substring gives seemingly random results, even when its parameters seem correct

Tags: c++, string, substring

My code should read in two or more authors names, separated by a comma, then return the last name of the first author.

```
cout << "INPUT AUTHOR: " << endl ;
getline(cin, authors, '\n') ;

int AuthorCommaLocation = authors.find(",",0) ;
int AuthorBlankLocation = authors.rfind(" ", AuthorCommaLocation) ;

string AuthorLast = authors.substr(AuthorBlankLocation+1, AuthorCommaLocation-1) ;
cout << AuthorLast << endl ;
```

However, when I try and retrieve the `AuthorLast` substring, it returns text anywhere from three to one character too long. Any insight into my error?

Comment: Here is a reference for the [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function. It takes `position` and `length` as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ `substr` method does not take in a start and end position.  Instead, it takes in a start position and a number of characters to read.  As a result, the arguments you are passing in are telling `substr` to start at position `AuthorBlankLocation + 1` and then to read `AuthorCommaLocation - 1` characters from that point forward, which is probably far too many characters.

If you want to specify the begin and end positions, you can use the iterator version of the `string` constructor:

```
string AuthorLast(authors.begin() + (AuthorBlankLocation + 1),
                  authors.begin() + (AuthorCommaLocation - 1));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just double-checked the Standard and can't find a `std::string::substr` that takes iterators.

Comment: When I try and run that code instead of the relevant portion of mine, I get the error : 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::substr' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Mystr>' to 'unsigned int'

Comment: @Douko- My apologies - that was the wrong way to do it.  I have edited my answer to reference the `string` constructor, rather than `substr`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace- You're correct - my code was incorrect.  I've just updated it.